# Choosing raster format for QField?

Tags: raster, qfield

I'm doing some tests with QField at the request of the company I work for.

I was wondering what is the best (most efficient and practical) raster format with regard to the fluidity and the loading speed while using the app on-the-field ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [QField documentation recommends using COG raster](https://docs.qfield.org/en/reference/data-format/#raster-data) for this purpose.

Other sources (citation needed) recommend mbtiles format.

Whatever you choose, here are a couple of things to consider:

- **Tiling** tiled data sources allow for loading only parts of the data and not always reading the whole dataset while rendering.
- **Pyramids** if pyramids are built, it's possible to render raster images much more efficient at small scale (zoomed out) because aggregated information is already available pre-calculated.
- **Compression** to make files small enough to fit on a handheld device, consider turning on some sort of compression. Raster data, like any non-random imagery, can normally be compressed very well (jpeg, png, ...) and for visual purpose like you have here, there's not even a need for a loss-less compression.

Have a look at the above link that provide some hints how to prepare the data using gdal commands (many of them are also available as QGIS processing algorithms)